# hello everyone,i have a problem in mongoDB compass,it still activating plugins from 3 hours ago

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem in MongoDB compass, it still activating plugins from 3 hours ago,
 I don't find any solutions.I think to uninstall and reinstall it but i have a data there and I'm afraid to forget it

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: I believe it is fixed in Compass version 1.21.2

Answer (score 0):

Try Compass Isolated Edition. i had the same problem before.